# C++ Reuse out-of-class comparsion operators of base for derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, code-reuse, comparison-operators

Snippet

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs.a == rhs.a; }

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const A& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const T& rhs, const A& lhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}

struct B : public A {
};

int main() {
    A a1, a2;
    B b1, b2;

    auto c1 = a1 == a2;
    auto c2 = static_cast<A>(b1) == static_cast<A>(b2);
    auto c3 = b1 == b2;
}
```

Is it possible to make the last comparison `b1 == b2` work without a `static_cast`?
Is a **reuse** of the out-of-class comparison operators of `A` possible without redefining explicit comparison operators for `B`?

Example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/enn53483a)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `A` is immutable to me. I have no access to it and its comparison operators.

Comment: Remove the `template`d operators - live - https://godbolt.org/z/az4e5zxGo

Comment: The template comparison operators are probably not a good idea. If you want to compare to an integer value, create operators for plain `ìnt` instead.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Can't. These overloads exist in the base class and are needed. Further, base is out of reach. This is just an example.

Comment: Then the template's can't work (as they access the base class - which is out of reach). I think you need to update the [mcve] to include the exact failing case.

Comment: How about making an overload for the `B` class? It can invoke the base-class comparison using `static_cast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the last comparison b1 == b2 work without a static_cast?

Yes, you can use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) as shown below:

```
bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs.a == rhs.a; }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, B>, bool > operator==(const A& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, B>,bool> operator==(const T& rhs, const A& lhs) {
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}
int main() {
    A a1, a2;
    B b1, b2;

    auto c1 = a1 == a2;
    auto c2 = b1 == b2; //works now 
    auto c3 = b1 == b2;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4q9Krdq4c).

---

Or with C++20 use `requires`

```
bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs.a == rhs.a; }

template <typename T> bool operator==(const A& lhs, const T& rhs) 
requires (!std::is_same_v<T, B>)
{
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}

template <typename T>bool  operator==(const T& rhs, const A& lhs) 
requires (!std::is_same_v<T, B>)
{
    return lhs.a == rhs;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TqbsbYxbo)

Comment: Great idea! Problem is I have no access to base class. Edit added in OP.

Comment: @Juergen I didn't change anything in base class `A`, so this should work.

Comment: I have also no access to the comparison functions for A. I can only work with B and want to avoid rewriting >30 operators.

Comment: @Juergen I see, this was very important information that should've been there in the original question. But since it wasn't there and I've already posted the answer(and made the effort in terms of time etc), I will keep this answer here. Hope you don't mind. You  also always have the option to ask a separate question with your requirement.

Comment: Sure, I will accept, since it solves the original question without the edit. Thanks for your efforts.